# How to write lambda function with arguments? c++

Tags: c++, argument-passing, stdthread, inline-functions

I want to call a method (for this example std::thread constructor) 
with lambda function, passing int value:

```
int a=10;

std::thread _testThread = thread([a](int _a){
  //do stuff using a or _a ?
});
_testThread.detach();
```

I don't know how to properly write such function, I get this error:
C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

Comment: You will have to capture `_a`, as you capture `a`.

Comment: well I need just 'a' inside that thread.

Comment: Thats a lambda function

Comment: The why do you have a parameter called `_a`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`std::thread` takes a callable object as well as any arguments to pass to it. If you give no arguments, `std::thread` will try to call that object with no arguments, hence the error.

If you need a parameter:

```
std::thread _testThread{[a](int _a) {
    std::cout << a << ' ' << _a; //prints main's a, followed by somethingThatWillBe_a
}, somethingThatWillBe_a};
```

If you're just trying to use `main`'s `a`, it's already captured:

```
std::thread _testThread{[a] {
    std::cout << a; //prints main's a
}};
```

I would also recommend being super careful if you think you need to detach a thread. If there's any possibility of joining the thread instead, go for it.

Answer (score 4):

You can access `int a` in one of two ways. Either pass it in as a parameter to the thread's constructor or capture it in the lambda's closure:

```
int a=10;

// pass in a as a parameter
std::thread _testThread1([](int _a){

  //do stuff using a or _a ?

}, a); // pass a to the parameter _a
_testThread1.detach();

// capture a in the closure
std::thread _testThread2([a](){ // capture a

  //do stuff using a or _a ?

});
_testThread2.detach();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to pass some value to lambda function, look at my code below:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;

    [](int arg)
    {
        cout << "arg = " << arg << endl;
    }
    (a);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to make thread with lambda function and passing to it some arguments see next code example:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;

    thread thd([](int arg) { cout << "arg = " << arg << endl; }, a);

    thd.join();

    return 0;
}
```